What is the theroy behind `mod2_res_ternary` in Falcon-768?
I am currently intrested in Falcon (PQC alg.). And I noticed that the Falcon team remove the parameter 768, which seems more complex compared to other two parameters.
There is a method called mod2_res_ternary, I don't understand the theory behind this. What is the resultant of polynomial f with phi and why the switch case doing so?
/*
 * Compute resultant of polynomial f with phi, modulo 2. This function
 * is for phi = X^N-X(N/2)+1, where N = 1.5*2^logn.
 */
static unsigned
mod2_res_ternary(const int16_t *f, unsigned logn)
{
    /*
     * We lower down the degree to 6, by successive degree halving:
     * we replace f with N(f). If:
     *   f = f0(x^2) + x*f1(x^2)
     * with f0 and f1 taken modulo X^(N/2)-(X^N/4)+1, then:
     *   N(f) = f0^2 - x*f1^2
     *
     * From f expressed as an array of bits:
     *   - f0 and f1 are obtained by extracting bits at even and
     *     odd indexes, respectively;
     *   - the "holes" are squeezed out to get down to degree N/2;
     *   - squarings (f0^2 and f1^2) compute the exact opposite of
     *     that "squeezing out", so in practice we skip both; but
     *     we must reduce modulo X^(N/2)-X^(N/4)+1.
     */

    uint32_t b[24];
    size_t u, n;

    /*
     * Extract bits into an array of 32-bit words.
     */
    n = MKN(logn, 1);
    // printf("%d\n", n);
    memset(b, 0, sizeof b);
    for (u = 0; u < n; u ++) {
        uint32_t bit;

        bit = (uint32_t)f[u] & 1;
        b[u >> 5] |= bit << (u & 31);
    }

    /*
     * Halve the degree repeatedly.
     *
     * If the input is: a0 || a1 || a2 || a3
     * Then we must compute: (a0 XOR a2 XOR a3) || (a1 XOR a2)
     */
    switch (logn) {
    case 9:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0..5]
         * a1 = b[6..11]
         * a2 = b[12..17]
         * a3 = b[18..23]
         */
        b[0] ^= b[12] ^ b[18];
        b[1] ^= b[13] ^ b[19];
        b[2] ^= b[14] ^ b[20];
        b[3] ^= b[15] ^ b[21];
        b[4] ^= b[16] ^ b[22];
        b[5] ^= b[17] ^ b[23];
        b[6] ^= b[12];
        b[7] ^= b[13];
        b[8] ^= b[14];
        b[9] ^= b[15];
        b[10] ^= b[16];
        b[11] ^= b[17];
        /* fall through */
    case 8:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0..2]
         * a1 = b[3..5]
         * a2 = b[6..8]
         * a3 = b[9..11]
         */
        b[0] ^= b[6] ^ b[9];
        b[1] ^= b[7] ^ b[10];
        b[2] ^= b[8] ^ b[11];
        b[3] ^= b[6];
        b[4] ^= b[7];
        b[5] ^= b[8];
        /* fall through */
    case 7:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0] || b[1](0..15)
         * a1 = b[1](16..31) || b[2]
         * a2 = b[3] || b[4](0..15)
         * a3 = b[4](16..31) || b[5]
         */
        b[0] ^= b[3] ^ (b[4] >> 16) ^ (b[5] << 16);
        b[1] ^= (b[4] & 0xFFFF) ^ (b[5] >> 16);
        b[1] ^= (b[3] << 16);
        b[2] ^= (b[3] >> 16) ^ (b[4] << 16);
        /* fall through */
    case 6:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0](0..23)
         * a1 = b[0](24..31) || b[1](0..15)
         * a2 = b[1](16..31) || b[2](0..7)
         * a3 = b[2](8..31)
         */
        b[0] ^= (b[1] >> 16) ^ ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 16) ^ (b[2] >> 8);
        b[0] ^= ((b[1] << 8) & 0xFF000000);
        b[1] ^= (b[1] >> 24) ^ ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8);
        b[1] &= 0xFFFF;
        /* fall through */
    case 5:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0](0..11)
         * a1 = b[0](12..23)
         * a2 = b[0](24..31) || b[1](0..3)
         * a3 = b[1](4..15)
         */
        b[0] ^= (b[0] >> 24) ^ ((b[1] & 0x0F) << 8) ^ (b[1] >> 4);
        b[0] ^= ((b[0] >> 12) & 0xFF000) ^ ((b[1] & 0x0F) << 20);
        b[0] &= 0xFFFFFF;
        /* fall through */
    case 4:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0](0..5)
         * a1 = b[0](6..11)
         * a2 = b[0](12..17)
         * a3 = b[0](18..23)
         */
        b[0] ^= ((b[0] >> 12) & 0x3F) ^ ((b[0] >> 18) & 0x3F);
        b[0] ^= ((b[0] >> 6) & 0xFC0);
        b[0] &= 0xFFF;
        /* fall through */
    case 3:
        /*
         * a0 = b[0](0..2)
         * a1 = b[0](3..5)
         * a2 = b[0](6..8)
         * a3 = b[0](9..11)
         */
        b[0] ^= ((b[0] >> 6) & 0x7) ^ ((b[0] >> 9) & 0x7);
        b[0] ^= ((b[0] >> 3) & 0x38);
        b[0] &= 0x3F;
        /* fall through */
    case 2:
        break;
    }

    /*
     * When we are done to phi = X^6-X^3+1, we have only 64
     * possibilities. It turns out that all of them except 0 yield
     * a resultant of value 1 with phi (modulo 2).
     */
    return b[0] != 0;
}


What the resultant is is easy to point to, see resultant (Polynomial). I don't remember offhand why Falcon needs this though, so I'll just leave this pointer for now.
